# Error when building core-image-weston with meta-chromium and meta-clang in dunfell branch (yocto)

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APIQq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h864K.png)

Can someone have any idea of that ,

Comment: The error is not clear, please share the full error log

Answer (score 0):

You have to use clang12 branch instead of dunfell.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).